# When running: help() in Terminal, it gives error: ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException

Tags: python, terminal

I am new to Anaconda and Python. I tried running: `help()` in Terminal and get error:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\Josep\Documents\My Documents\AIOPython\MyCode> python --version
Python 3.8.5
PS C:\Users\Josep\Documents\My Documents\AIOPython\MyCode> help()
**At line:1 char:6**
**+ help()**
**An expression was expected after '('.**
    **+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [],** **ParentContainsErrorRecordException**
    **+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedExpression**
```

I also tried adding the path to Python.exe to end of my Path statement and restarting (still get error).
c:\users\josep\anaconda3\python.exe

Hoping you can advise what I need to do to resolve this.  Thanks.

Comment: By using the `--version` option you are making the Python interpreter output just its version information and immediately exit, instead of entering its interactive REPL shell, where you can enter expressions such as `help()`.

Comment: Just a quick check - potentially a simple solution.  Have you tried entering the word python first. Then on the next line try help().  When you enter python you should see it switch from PS C:\ ... \MyCode> to >>>

Comment: excellent.  that last suggestion of entering word python first resolved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`help()` is used inside the Python interpreter, like

```py
>>> help()
help> ...
```

*Edit*:

You enter the Python interpreter by first typing `python3`. Then you will be prompted with the `>>>` .

Comment: Well, maybe you could, but only if it is a defined command in the shell you're using. And then it wouldn't be the Python `help` but a different `help`.

Comment: Actually what resolved it was comment above: Just a quick check - potentially a simple solution. Have you tried entering the word python first. Then on the next line try help(). When you enter python you should see it switch from PS C:\ ... \MyCode> to >>> – LPR 35 mins ago

Comment: Yes, I'll add that for future reference.